# Scrollbars not working correctly in nested grid from UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

The User Control is insert Dynamically at runtime from Application into the Mainwindow.
My Problem is that the Scrollbars are not working...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="50" Background="#FF2E3137" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel Margin="10 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <!--Label inside-->
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!--Stack Panel with buttons inside-->
        </StackPanel>
        <Separator VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Separator>

    </Grid>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="16"     
          Background="#FF2E3137" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"     
          CanUserAddRows="False"     
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="50"  IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bezeichnung" Binding="{Binding BEZEICHNUNG}" Width="350"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

The result looks like this:  No button Bar from Grid Row 1
[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFlNi.png)

The result looks like this: Picture 2
[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BduO9.png)

This should be the result with the buttons in GridRow 1, in GridRow 2 the Datagrid is nested and the Scrollbars should appear and work correctly.
It seems that the Grid grows vertically infinity so the Scrollbar will not appear...

The Sample hides the buttons in Row 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem wasn't the Control itsel.
The Problem was one Stage higher in the Mainwindow where the control was nested.
There was a grid and not a Dockpanel...

This was the Problem, The gris grows and the usercontrol also. So you will never see a Scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need a ScrollViewer.
2. I think the outermost Grid is expanding to fit to the height of the DataGrid. You can check the height of this Grid from live visual tree. If it's true, a DockPanel may solve this problem by filling the rest of the window.

   ```
   <Control Name="parentControl">
     <Grid Name="outermostGrid">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <Grid Grid.Row="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="50" Background="#FF2E3137" VerticalAlignment="Top">
         <StackPanel Margin="10 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
           <!--Label inside-->
         </StackPanel>
         <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
           <!--Stack Panel with buttons inside-->
         </StackPanel>
         <Separator VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Separator>

       </Grid>

       <!--DataGrid has its own scrollviewer-->
       <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="16"     
         Background="#FF2E3137" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"     
         CanUserAddRows="False"     
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="50"  IsReadOnly="True" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bezeichnung" Binding="{Binding BEZEICHNUNG}" Width="350"/>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>
     </Grid>
   </Control>
   ```

Ensure that outermostGrid fills its parent and parentControl is not auto expanding.

Comment: Can you provide a sample how to do that? Iam new in WPF. tried it but didn't work...